# How do I replicate SuperTrend indicator from Binance website?

Tags: python, pandas, algorithmic-trading, pandas-ta

I'm trying to implement (in Python) SuperTrend indicator that you can see on Binance website if you click on TradingView tab and add it [here](https://www.binance.com/en/futures/ETHUSDT)

So far I've tried multiple various ways of calculating it as well as TA-Lib and pandas-ta. None of those are exactly the same with the Binance version. What am I missing?

I'm feeding the indicator from closed candles data(Klines with X parameter) with 1000 samples like so:

```
st_df = ta.supertrend(high=ticker_df['high'].tail(1000),\
low=ticker_df['low'].tail(1000), close=ticker_df['price'].tail(1000), \
length=10, multiplier=3)
```

My dataframe is fine - I'm getting exactly the same(as shown on Binance) EMA and other indicators with pandas-ta from it.

Answer (score 2):

try as it is

```
st1 = df.ta.supertrend(period=10, multiplier=2)['SUPERT_7_2.0'];
```

Comment: Still not the same numbers as on Binance.

Answer (score 0):

```
st= ta.supertrend(df['high'],df['low'],df['close'],10,2)
#print(st);
df= df.join(st);
print(df)
```